# TypeError: bodyParser.urlencoded is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

this always show the above problem in the console. If anybody has face it before, then help me. thank you!

Comment: can you show how you're requiring `body-parser`?

Comment: const bodyParser = express("body-parser");

Comment: Than you sir thanks very much. I replaced the body-parser with express and it got fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Express version below `4.16`,

```
npm i body-parser
```

Now in your main `app.js or server.js or index.js` file, require `body-parser` as shown below,

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

This should resolve your error.

If you are using Express above `v4.16` you don't need to add an additional `body-parser` package to your application

Replace

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

with

```
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

References:

- https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c
- https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Than you sir thanks very much. I replaced the body-parser with express and it got fixed. Thanks a lot.